# Prevent execution of parent li event when clicking on link in child ul

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

If I have a list ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gelgamek/s6tstjat/)) where:

- a click listener is added to all `<li>` nodes containing a child list
- every child list's `<li>` node contains a link

how should I allow those links to behave normally when clicked? Note that despite the link node being the first child of the parent list in my example, I'm also wanting to consider examples where that may not be the case.

I'm using only **pure JS, no JQuery**.

I can think of 2 solutions, each with different potential use cases:

1. Check the event target or a related node matches a particular condition ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gelgamek/ahsu2wh3/)).
2. Remove the event listener from the parent and reattach it later ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gelgamek/12rbq0nk/)).

Are there any other ways to achieve the same thing? Assuming a use case where any method could work, would one be preferable to another (on the face of it, the first example looks much cleaner)?

Comment: Since you have a link as first child of those LI that contain futher lists - you might as well handle the click on that link, instead of the parent LI - then you would not even _have_ this problem ... // If the choice is only between the two methods above, then I'd pick 1, always. Constantly adding and removing event handlers is just messy, and asking for trouble in the long run.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wanting to bear in mind situations where the link might not be the first child, so I've updated my question. I figured event handlers were much messier; thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: If those links will always be children of the LI (as opposed to descendants, further down), then you can still use CSS selectors like `li > a` with querySelectorAll to only bind the handlers to those links in the first place, no matter what number child of the LI they are.